# Time domain reflectometry (TDR), initial pulse slope

Tags: signal, cables, transmission-line, coax, tdr

A ~100kHz square wave through a 100m open end coax (RG-58) produces a slightly sloped shoulder during the time from initial pulse until reflected pulse (A-B), and from initial pulse drops until reflected pulse ends (C-D).

What are the correct explanations for these slopes [not being flat]?

(Scaling: 2.0V/ 2us/)
[image]
[image]
EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Maybe the driver impedance is changing due to temperature sensitive impedance. What is the driving source? What is the nature of the source resistance?

Comment: It could also be source capacitance.

Comment: impedance, capacitance or inductance, depending on where it is and how the whole setup is done, which we know nothing about

Comment: See edit: function generator.

Comment: What kind of connection do you have to the scope? What is the input impedance? 50 Ohms?

Comment: @Ali Chen, I can't say 100% certain, but very likely it was set at 50ohm and it's a 1m 50ohm cable to the scope. The 100m coax is on a small spool.

Comment: Ok, Keysight specs for your scope (DSO-X 2002A) reveals that it does not have 50-Ohm terminated input, only a standard 1-MOhm, with 11pF in parallel. Driving 15V into 50 Ohm would require a lot of challenge from the signal generator, and might fry a 50-Ohm scope input (normal limits for 50-Ohm is 5Vrms). So you are good (almost), and should have another reflection, from 1m cable (in 13-15ns time frame). The glitch near point C is likely it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slope on a shoulder (first plateau) is defined by interplay of resistive and dielectric losses in the transmission line (cable), see the iconic source, [by Howard Johnson](http://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/edn/LossyLine.htm). In your case the resistive loss effect seems to dominate.

There are also 13,000 hits on Google for [tdr lossy transmission line], from Tektronix and Agilent and other good places.